# How can I use the routes, but not change the URL?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building a Single Page Application(SPA), whose domain is `http://teachme.com`. The routes could be seen as

```
teachApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,       $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/teach/', {templateUrl: 'views/login_view.html'}).
        when('/teach/overview', {templateUrl: 'views/overview_view.html'}).
        when('/teach/users', {templateUrl: 'views/users_view.html'}).
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/teach/'});
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Now everytime i click on the tabs, the route changes and I see the different view, but URL changes to

```
http://teachme.com/#teach
http://teachme.com/#teach/overview
http://teachme.com/#teach/users
```

which fails the whole point of keeping the url unique and for bookmark purposes. Is there a way that routes work fine, but the URL stays to `http://teachme.com`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of routes is to use [deep linking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_linking), per [the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07).

The domain & path components of your URL will always remain constant, however the component after the *#* is what changes, which allows bookmarks to work even though you are creating a single page app.

Short version is No, routing will not work if you don't want the portion of the URL after the *#* to be changed.  To me it seems like you loose value for bookmarking in the absence of such additions.

Even on a single page app, you can bookmark the *teach* or *overview* section etc.  Maybe you provide a *bookmark* link which always stamps the domain by itself in the bookmark for the user.

Comment: In all fairness, I looked through some of the apps on [this page](http://webdesignledger.com/inspiration/21-inspiring-single-page-websites).  The URL never changes, not even after the _#_.  Some of the links are pointing to _/#some-section_ but the URL still doesn't change.  They're probably just preventing the default anchor behavior there.  I dunno, personally I find the Angular approach more advanced since the back button still works and you can directly link into some particular page/state of the app.

Comment: Thanks for all your effort, I read through the pages and realized that Angular approach is better